# String x ticks not scaling data in D3

Tags: d3.js

`

```js
var margin = {top: 50, right: 50, bottom: 50, left: 50}
  , width = window.innerWidth - margin.left - margin.right 
  , height = window.innerHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom; 

// n data points 
var n = 7;

// X scale
var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
    .domain(['A','B','C','D','F','E','Z']) // input
    .range([0, width]); // output

// Y scale 
var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 1]) 
    .range([height, 0]); 


var line = d3.line()
    .x(function(d, i) { return xScale(i); }) 
    .y(function(d) { return yScale(d.y); }) 
    .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX) 


var dataset = d3.range(n).map(function(d) { return {"y": d3.randomUniform(1)()} })


// SVGs 
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
 .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
svg.append("rect")
    .attr("width", "100%")
    .attr("height", "100%")
    .attr("fill", "white");

svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
// x axis call 
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale)); 

// y axis call 
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale)); 


svg.append("path")
    .datum(dataset) 
    .attr("class", "line") 
    .attr("d", line); 

// 12. Appends a circle for each datapoint 
svg.selectAll(".dot")
    .data(dataset)
  .enter().append("circle") // Uses the enter().append() method
    .attr("class", "dot") // Assign a class for styling
    .attr("cx", function(d, i) { return xScale(i) })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return yScale(d.y) })
    .attr("r", 6);
 
 svg.append("text")
      .attr("class", "title")
      .attr("x", width/2)
      .attr("y", 0 - (margin.top / 2))
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text("Testing");
```

```css
/* 13. Basic Styling with CSS */

/* Style the lines by removing the fill and applying a stroke */
.line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: green;
    stroke-width: 3;
}

/* Style the dots by assigning a fill and stroke */
.dot {
    fill: red;
    stroke: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style type="text/css">


</style>
<!-- Body tag is where we will append our SVG and SVG objects-->
<body>
</body>

<!-- Load in the d3 library -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>
</script>
```

I need for each data point to correspond to an (string) x-coordinate.

I am knew to d3 and I have yet to get accustomed to formatting axis.

I would also be great if anyone can point me out to how to add a tooltip. (Just an explanation)

Thank you everyone.

Not sure why it keeps saying your: "
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."
`

Comment: Dear Mixter. Please create separate posts for each question which is independant of the other. Also post some code of what you have tried.

Comment: How is it independent? Code is there!!!!!!!

Comment: Ok you added the code after posting. Also tooltip is independant of axis issue, that's why I asked to post it separately. Let me take a look. It seems that your x-axis is producing the strings. So could you please clarify what you would like as your end product? Is it that you want your points to displace to particular x-coordinates based on the x-axis strings?

Comment: Yep. It's that simple. I tried it with #s but could not do it with strings. Thanks

Comment: Please do not worry about the random generation of y-data. Even var y = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]; var x = ['A','B','C','D','E','F',G'] will work

Comment: I have added the solution. For the tooltip I suggest the following: https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/257c360b3650b9f0a52dd8257d7a2d73

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scaleOrdinal is mapped to an array of alphabets but when you are calculating the cx you are mapping to an integer `i`. To resolve this:

Separate the labels as as array first:

```
var labels = ['A','B','C','D','F','E','Z'];
```

Then pass the labels to the domain:

```
// X scale
var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
    .domain(labels) // input
    .range([0, width]); // output
```

Finally, when you call calculate the cx, you need to send a value which was used in the domain. In your case since your domain is an array of alphabets you need to reparse the `i` to that particular alphabet. Hence you need to `return xScale(labels[i])` as below:

```
svg.selectAll(".dot")
    .data(dataset)
  .enter().append("circle") // Uses the enter().append() method
    .attr("class", "dot") // Assign a class for styling
    .attr("cx", function(d, i) { return xScale(labels[i]) })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return yScale(d.y) })
    .attr("r", 6);
```

Full working snippet below. Hope this helps.

```js
var margin = {top: 50, right: 50, bottom: 50, left: 50}
  , width = window.innerWidth - margin.left - margin.right 
  , height = window.innerHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom; 

// n data points 
var n = 7;

//labels
var labels = ['A','B','C','D','F','E','Z'];

// X scale
var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
    .domain(labels) // input
    .range([0, width]); // output

// Y scale 
var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 1]) 
    .range([height, 0]); 


var line = d3.line()
    .x(function(d, i) { return xScale(i); }) 
    .y(function(d) { return yScale(d.y); }) 
    .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX) 


var dataset = d3.range(n).map(function(d) { return {"y": d3.randomUniform(1)()} })


// SVGs 
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
 .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
svg.append("rect")
    .attr("width", "100%")
    .attr("height", "100%")
    .attr("fill", "white");

svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
// x axis call 
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale)); 

// y axis call 
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale)); 


svg.append("path")
    .datum(dataset) 
    .attr("class", "line") 
    .attr("d", line); 

// 12. Appends a circle for each datapoint 
svg.selectAll(".dot")
    .data(dataset)
  .enter().append("circle") // Uses the enter().append() method
    .attr("class", "dot") // Assign a class for styling
    .attr("cx", function(d, i) { return xScale(labels[i]) })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return yScale(d.y) })
    .attr("r", 6);
 
 svg.append("text")
      .attr("class", "title")
      .attr("x", width/2)
      .attr("y", 0 - (margin.top / 2))
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text("Testing");
```

```css
/* 13. Basic Styling with CSS */

/* Style the lines by removing the fill and applying a stroke */
.line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: green;
    stroke-width: 3;
}

/* Style the dots by assigning a fill and stroke */
.dot {
    fill: red;
    stroke: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style type="text/css">


</style>
<!-- Body tag is where we will append our SVG and SVG objects-->
<body>
</body>

<!-- Load in the d3 library -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>
</script>
```

Updated Snippet with Lines:

```js
var margin = {top: 50, right: 50, bottom: 50, left: 50}
  , width = window.innerWidth - margin.left - margin.right 
  , height = window.innerHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom; 

// n data points 
var n = 7;

//labels
var labels = ['A','B','C','D','F','E','Z'];

// X scale
var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
    .domain(labels) // input
    .range([0, width]); // output

// Y scale 
var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 1]) 
    .range([height, 0]); 


var line = d3.line()
    .x(function(d, i) { return xScale(labels[i]); }) 
    .y(function(d) { return yScale(d.y); }) 
    .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX) 


var dataset = d3.range(n).map(function(d) { return {"y": d3.randomUniform(1)()} })


// SVGs 
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
 .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
svg.append("rect")
    .attr("width", "100%")
    .attr("height", "100%")
    .attr("fill", "white");

svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
// x axis call 
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale)); 

// y axis call 
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale)); 


svg.append("path")
    .datum(dataset) 
    .attr("class", "line") 
    .attr("d", line); 

// 12. Appends a circle for each datapoint 
svg.selectAll(".dot")
    .data(dataset)
  .enter().append("circle") // Uses the enter().append() method
    .attr("class", "dot") // Assign a class for styling
    .attr("cx", function(d, i) { return xScale(labels[i]) })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return yScale(d.y) })
    .attr("r", 6);
 
 svg.append("text")
      .attr("class", "title")
      .attr("x", width/2)
      .attr("y", 0 - (margin.top / 2))
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text("Testing");
```

```css
/* 13. Basic Styling with CSS */

/* Style the lines by removing the fill and applying a stroke */
.line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: green;
    stroke-width: 3;
}

/* Style the dots by assigning a fill and stroke */
.dot {
    fill: red;
    stroke: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style type="text/css">


</style>
<!-- Body tag is where we will append our SVG and SVG objects-->
<body>
</body>

<!-- Load in the d3 library -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>
</script>
```

Comment: Note: the "Run code snippet" squishes the plot in height because the height of the plot is based on the `window.innerHeight`, which in this case becomes small.

Comment: Correct. I figured it when I tested my post. Thanks for the prompt response.

Comment: I am not seeing the connecting line! I just noticed, lol. There should be a green line connecting the data as per the js and css. But why would it vanish?

Comment: In your original post as well, the line was not being rendered. The issue was the same, your x values were trying to be calculated by the index integer against a domain which was alphabets. Therefore I did the same thing and apply the `.x(function(d, i) { return xScale(labels[i]); }) ` to the `line`

Comment: I thought it had to do  with the misalignment of the data with respect to the x-coords.

Comment: If you inspect your original code you will see a lot of `NaN` values in the `d` attribute of the line. This was because it was not able to calculate the x coordinates due to the aforementioned problem.

Comment: How much work to get this to work in the latest d3 version? I tried v5 from their site but the data does not align with y axis properly. If you can just direct me to what to fix I can give it a good fight. Unless the fix is trivial.

Comment: Going from D3 v4 to v5 is easy, because the only major change was in how the data was retrieved. D3 v5 uses fetch api which uses promises. Read more here https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch. If you get stuck and need more help on that create another question for it with the code as it is a separate issue.